# How to solve RenderStack error when using List.view

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to implement something like this inside a `listView`:

[image]

But when I implement the code below, i get render box error:

> > RenderStack object was given an infinite size during layout. I/flutter (16418): The following RenderObject was being processed when
> >     the exception was fired: I/flutter (16418):   RenderStack#10b27
> >     relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT I/flutter (16418):
> >     creator: Stack ← RepaintBoundary-[<0>] ← IndexedSemantics ← I/flutter
> >     (16418):   NotificationListener ← KeepAlive ←
> >     AutomaticKeepAlive ← SliverList ← I/flutter (16418):   MediaQuery ←
> >     SliverPadding ← Viewport ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#7cbed] ← Semantics
> >     ← ⋯ I/flutter (16418):   parentData:  (can use size) I/flutter
> >     (16418):   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=411.4, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
> >     I/flutter (16418):   size: Size(411.4, Infinity) I/flutter (16418):
> >     alignment: center I/flutter (16418):   textDirection: ltr I/flutter
> >     (16418):   fit: loose I/flutter (16418):   overflow: clip

How can fix this problem?

Code:

```
Scaffold(
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: model.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return _buildCard(context, index);
          },
        )
        );
  }
}

Widget _buildCard(
    BuildContext context, int index) {
  return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Positioned(
        top: 80.0,
        right: 30.0,
        left: 30.0,
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.12,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.black),
        ),
      ),
      Positioned(
        top: 20,
        child: Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              shape: BoxShape.circle,
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 13.0)),
        ),
      )
    ],
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give the stack a widget, and the stack will be the same size as the first widget.

Otherwise, stack has no size and Positioned cannot be located.

```
Widget _buildCard(BuildContext context, int index) {
return Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
        Container(
        height: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .size
            .height * 0.12,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black),
        ),
        Positioned(
            top: 80.0,
            right: 30.0,
            left: 30.0,
            child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery
                    .of(context)
                    .size
                    .height * 0.12,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.black),
            ),
        ),
        Positioned(
            top: 20,
            child: Container(
                height: 100,
                width: 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    shape: BoxShape.circle,
                    border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 13.0)),
            ),
        )
    ],
);
```

}